# Can't UPDATE password even though all validations are passed

Tags: php, mysql

Could you check whats wrong with my code? Cause it passes the validations but doesn't update my old password with a new one... i even try to echo values after successful UPDATE and at the end it returns me my old password instead of new one.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Profilio redagavimas</title>
<link href="CSS/stilius.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="CSS/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php require("includes/validate.php");?>
<?php require("includes/stilius.php");?>
<?php
echo "Jūsų vardas: ".$row["name"]."<br>";
echo "Jūsų miestas: ".$row["city"]."<br>";
echo "Jūsų telefono numeris: ".$row["phone"]."<br>";
if(strlen($row["web"]) > 0)
    echo "Jūsų svetainės adresas: ".$row["web"]."<br>";
else
    echo "Registracijos metu neįvedėte savo svetainės adreso."."<br>";
    echo "pass";
?>

<form method='post' action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                <td>Old Password:</td>                  
                <td><input name='oldpw' type='password' required='required'/></td>
            <tr>
                <td>New Password:</td>
                <td><input name='newpw' type='password' required = 'required' /></td>
            <tr>                    
                <td>Confirm Password:</td>                  
                <td><input name='conpw' type='password' required = 'required' /></td>
                <td> 
                <input type='submit' value='Pakeisti slaptažodį' />
                </td>
            </tr> 
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['newpw'])){    
$newpwd = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['newpw']));
if (md5($_POST['oldpw'])== $row['pass'])
{
    if ($_POST['newpw']==$_POST['conpw'])
    {
        if(mysql_query("UPDATE vartotojai SET pass='$newpwd' WHERE 'V_ID' = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}'"))
        {
            echo $newpwd."<br>";
            echo $_SESSION['user_id']."<br>";
            echo "Slaptažodis sėkmingai pakeistas"."<br>";
            echo $row['pass'];
        }
        else {echo "Klaida: " .mysql_error();}
    }
    else { echo "Slaptažodžiai nesutampa"; }
}

else { echo "Įvestas blogas senas slaptažodis";}
}
?>
<?php mysql_close(); ?>

<?php require("includes/footer.php");?>      
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT: SOLVED** Thanks to Shankar Damodaran.

Comment: Remove the quotes from `'V_ID'`

Comment: try to echo the query and check whether there is any error in it

Comment: The mysql extension has been deprecated, use PDO or mysqli because they're more stable and secure.

Comment: Thanks Shankar Damodaran :D such a stupid mistake... you saved my day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newpwd = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['newpw']));
```

The approach within this single line is completely wrong for several reasons:

1. You allow several passwords to match the same hash because of the escaping. Thus, the order is wrong and should be:

   `$newpwd = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['newpw']));`
2. One step further, you don't even need to escape an md5 hash because it only consist of alpha-numeric hex digits:

   `$newpwd = md5($_POST['newpw']);`
3. Using md5 password hashing without salt is 100% equal to using clear-text passwords. Even with salt, it's still very unsecure. Alternatives:

   http://php.net/function.password-hash

   https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

The issue itself is in the UPDATE:

```
"UPDATE vartotojai SET pass='$newpwd' WHERE 'V_ID' = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}'"
```

Should be

```
"UPDATE vartotojai SET pass='" . $newpwd . "' WHERE V_ID = '" . $row["V_ID"] . "'"
```

Using the V_ID you already selected (I guess you have) is more secure than using something from the session. Normal single quotes arround columns tell MySQL "this is not a column".

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if(mysql_query("UPDATE `vartotojai` SET `pass`='$newpwd' WHERE `V_ID` = '$session_user_id' LIMIT 1 "))
 {
```

Note : `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `pdo`

Comment: Why do you put up an extra variable for the user's id?

Comment: Just asking... +1 for `LIMIT 1`

Comment: I can't use mysqli or pdo cause this is studies project and we need to use mysql